# Аналог команды which (linux) в cmd?

Tags: bash, cmd

Как в *cmd* узнать какая именно версия программы вызывается? 
Например в *linux* для этого есть замечательная команда *which*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В версии Windows Server 2003 и выше появилась программа `where.exe`. Выполняет точно то же, что и `which` в Linux. Не работает для встроенных в shell команд типа `cd`. Для справки используйте `where /?`.

[Ссылка на оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line)

Comment: чуть опередил))

Comment: @IntFloat, да я почти 20 минут ждал пока кто-нибудь из системщиков  ответит. Не дождался. )

Comment: @LEQADA, поправьте опечатку)) Вы перепутали где `which`, а где `where`).

Answer (score 0):

В Windows есть команда `where`, появилась в Windows Vista и Windows Server 2003.